# special character come with code in the url

Tags: php, wordpress

I have user this for getting a url in each option.

```
        <select name="min_price" class="orderby">
                        <option value="1&max_price=100">1 - 100</option>
                        <option value="101&max_price=200">101 - 200</option>
                        <option value="201&max_price=300">201 - 300</option>
                </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="paged" value="1">
```

It is working now. But the filter is not working. Like i selected second option, the url has changed by this `www.mydoian.com/shop/?min_price=101%26max_price%253D200`.

I want this should be written like this

```
www.mydoian.com/shop/?min_price=101&max_price=200
```

How can i get this url ? Is there anything what i miss ?

Comment: when you put special characters in the parameters it will be automatically encoded, and when you receive in on the server end you can decode it by `urldecode()` function.

Comment: The browser takes care of URL-encoding the form field value for you here - it won't let you sneak in a second parameter through the _value_ of a field. You can not send two distinctive values using one form field that results in one form submission parameter.  _"I want this should be written like this"_ - you simply can't get that, not from a normal form submission - you would have to interfere with JavaScript before the form is send, or catch this server side and issue a redirect to the "correct" form expected.

Comment: Both not really worth the hassle - I would suggest you simply JSON-encode an array containing the lower and upper boundary you want to submit, so that they can be send as _one_ parameter value, and easily (validated and) taken apart again on the server side.

Comment: Would you consider creating 2 selects instead of one? One for min values with name **min_price** and one for max values with name **max_price**. Automatically the url will be `www.mydoian.com/shop/?min_price=101&max_price=200`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create 2 selects as the below and add some javascript to enable max_price options higher than the min_price:

```
<select name="min_price" class="orderby">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="101">101</option>
    <option value="201">201</option>
</select>
<select name="max_price" class="orderby">
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
</select>
```

Else you can create the one select for min price and a hidden input for max price. And on Select of the min_price you set the value of the max_price with javascript.

```
<select name="min_price" class="orderby">
    <option value="1">1 - 100</option>
    <option value="101">101 - 200</option>
    <option value="201">201 - 300</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="max_price" value="" />
```

These 2 methods will result in the url format you desire:

```
www.mydoian.com/shop/?min_price=101&max_price=200
```